# Is Updating Game will lose user existing data?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am developing a game with 20 levels(first 5 levels will be free and other 15 levels will be paid).In this game has special power to play the game,the user can purchase the powers and use it to play.In future i plan to add extra levels and special power to the game as different version.

My Question is in future when user updates the game,the existing purchased powers and unlocked levels will remains or else it will be updated as a new game.

I am using filemanager to store the data in my first version.

Comment: where do you store it ?

Comment: I am storing in documentsDirectory

Comment: is it correct or else give soe idea for this

Comment: What do you mean with "different version"? Just an update to the same app or another app on the App Store to be downloaded separately?

Comment: adding features to the same app and release as a different version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if user updated the existing app without deleting previous installed version (which we expect), then the documents directory data will not be modified/deleted. You will have your previous version's data on device.

Comment: I am not using Db for storing,I am using only Document directory with the file manager.Is it Correct

Comment: The documents directory is persistent, therefore your files are persistent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no effect when you will done migration on user default data and cached data as well as you db file. db file is only affected when you change db structure in latest update of aap. in that case you need some handling.

So in case of updating you need to handle migration. You can use these links for help

1. [Iphone data migration on application update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920195/iphone-data-migration-on-application-update)
2. [What is common data migration strategy for Core Data in iOS development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601339/what-is-common-data-migration-strategy-for-core-data-in-ios-development)
3. [Steps to migrate Core Data databases for shipped iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262352/steps-to-migrate-core-data-databases-for-shipped-iphone-apps)

Now as per you data management you need to short out your problem.

Comment: this is absolutely incorrect. I have updated many apps and have retained documents directory's data and even UserDefaults complete data

Answer (score 0):

If you are stroing data in document directory then data will be lost. so you need to store it on server

Comment: Apologize myself but is not correct, data in Documents directory are preserved during updates. They are deleted only if you delete the app.

Answer (score 0):

You have more option to save data:
Online:
-iCloud
-GameCenter (only for points, achievements)
-Your Server 
Offline
-Core Data (usually store is in doc folder)
-NSUserDefault
-Doc Dir

The 4,5 and 6 will be deleted only if user delete the app, now AppStore supports also delta updates. For purchase using IAP the will remain on the device after update but you always need a system to restore them.